# A Timer() thread still running after cancelling it

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I do not know why the thread is still alive even after i cancel  it? in the code below the  `Timer` thread implements `runnable` and in the code i want it to stay running for 7 seconds using `Thread.sleep(7000);`and after that i called `mTimer.cancel();` to kill the thread. during the 7 seconds the `run()` method should be called to execute a task that will last for 10 seconds. When i executed that program, the time of the first line was `12:18:37` and as i expected, since this thread will live only for 7 seconds before i cancel it, however the time of second line to be displayed was `05 12:18:44`, now this is 7 seconds difference and it is rational. But unexpectedly, after 3 seconds another line appeared on the console and it was timed to `05 12:18:47`. If you noticed the difference between the first and the third line you will find it 10 seconds.My question is, why the entire thread did not die after 7 seconds.

JavaCode:

```
public class TimerTaskExample extends TimerTask {
private static Timer mTimer;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("going to sleep at: " + new Date());
    dosomeWorks();
    System.out.println("returned back at: " + new Date());
}

private void dosomeWorks() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTaskExample();
    mTimer = new Timer(true);
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, new Date(), 2*1000);
    //System.out.println("timer will start now at: " + new Date());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mTimer.cancel();
     System.out.println("timer is cancelled now at: " + new Date());
     try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
going to sleep at: Mon May 05 12:18:37 CEST 2014
timer is cancelled now at: Mon May 05 12:18:44 CEST 2014
returned back at: Mon May 05 12:18:47 CEST 2014
```

Comment: The logical conclusion is you can't immediately cancel a sleeping Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelling a TimerTask does not interrupt it's execution - it just prevents it from being executed again.

If you want the thread to stop executing you need to stash a reference to the java.lang.Thread somewhere and interrupt it.

Assuming that you're doing real work in the thread you also need to poll Thread.interrupted() to check if it should continue.

```
private Thread taskThread;

@Override
public void run() {
    taskThread = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("going to sleep at: " + new Date());
    doSomeWorks();
    System.out.println("returned back at: " + new Date());
}

private void dosomeWorks() {
    for (int i = 0; !Thread.interrupted() && i < 10; ++i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

...
mTimer.cancel();
timerTask.taskThread.interrupt();
...
```

Be sure to read the javadoc for [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) to be sure you know it actually does.